# Multiple FB share buttons on one page - loads SLOW

Tags: wordpress, facebook, performance

I have a wordpress site that loads a lot of posts on one page and each post has a share button. When it gets to the share button it goes really slow and downloads and renders each button individually.Is there a way to only use one button and repeat it or streamline, cache the loading of these elements? Same goes for the twitter button, each button is a request from the server that the site has to wait to load.
Maybe I can cache the graphics or something?

Here's an example, http://www.anybarspecial.com/?gmw_post=specials&tax_days=43&tax_drink_types=0&gmw_address%5B%5D=&gmw_distance=3000&gmw_units=imperial&gmw_form=1&paged=1&gmw_per_page=50&gmw_lat=&gmw_lng=&gmw_px=pt&action=gmw_post

Comment: No, that is not possible. Each button renders as an individual iframe, that loads an individual URL. // The Feed and Share dialog have a version that can simply be called by linking to a certain URL – so you could replace those buttons with simple links, that won’t have to load anything from Facebook (unless the user clicks them, of course.) That is the fastest possible implementation – with the small drawback, that you won’t get a like counter. (But the count could be queried server-side via API and cached, so that outputting the number comes at no cost to the actual page rendering time.)

Comment: this was a good one, but it pulls a Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in... functions.php  http://danielsetzermann.com/webdesign/custom-social-media-buttons-for-wordpress-with-share-count/